# Character encoding in a GET request with http.client lib (Python)

Tags: python, utf-8, get, httprequest, python-3.3

I am a beginner in python and I coded this little script to send an HTTP GET request on my local server (localhost). It works great, except that I wish I could send Latin characters such as accents.

```
import http.client

httpMethod = "GET"
url = "localhost"
params = "Hello World"

def httpRequest(httpMethod, url, params):
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(url)
    conn.request(httpMethod, '/?param='+params)
    conn.getresponse().read()
    conn.close()
    return

httpRequest(httpMethod, url, params)
```

When I insert the words with accent in my parameter "params", this is the error message that appears:

*UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)*

I don't know if there is a solution using http.client library but I think so. When I look in the documentation http.client, I can see this:

**HTTPConnection.request**

Strings are encoded as ISO-8859-1, the default charset for HTTP

Comment: You need to call `params.encode('latin-1')`

Comment: It doesn't work, same error... Other ideas ? I think I have to change the library that I use but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't construct arguments manually. Use [`urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) instead:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlencode
>>> params = 'Aserejé'
>>> urlencode({'params': params})
'params=Aserej%C3%A9'
```

So, you can do:

```
conn.request(httpMethod, '/?' + urlencode({'params': params}))
```

*Also note that yout string will be encoded as UTF-8 before being URL-escaped*.

Comment: @ kirelagin Can we use urlencode for odata related filters also? As we are constructing our get urls using odata filters. Thanks

Comment: @GauravParek I’m sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about. You should probably ask a separate question